# How to create edit thumbnail feature as in facebook(while uploading display image) in Asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, ajax

I want to upload an image and want to show a particular part of image in the thumbnail of particular size. I want to customize the thumbnail look.

Comment: Come on guys, dont downvote new users. Just ask them questions like Verbeia did and try to help them improve there questions

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a combination of an ASPX page, some jQuery plugin like Image Crop (http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-image-crop-plugin-jcrop/) and a handler which accepts the changes made to the image using an AJAX call.

I think it would be pretty easy as long as the jQuery plugin supports the right events. Jcrop supports an onChange event, which you could use to send certain coordinates to a handler.

Edit: Someone already did this and wrote about it: http://www.omerfarukzorlu.com/post/ASPNET-Image-Croper-Component-with-JCrop.aspx

PS. Not sure about the downvoting. It is a new user, but StackOverflow does not supply complete solutions for most cases, but just tips and pointers to find the solution yourself.